# How do i detect type of packet in the kdd99 with svm?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm

I am researching on **Intrusion Detection system** and I want to implement IDS with SVM in Matlab. I use **Kdd99 as dataset**. The kdd99 dataset contains 41 features and is labeled as either normal or attack (there are 4 attack: `DOS`, `R2L`, `U2R` and `Probing`). I select about 9 features of this dataset and I try to normalization.

My questions is how detect the packet with this features? How do I know if this is attack or normal packet?

Comment: This sounds like a straight forward svm training and prediction problem, so I think I must not understand your question? Also, why only use 9 features out of the 41 available? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.First I try to select a few features and after read this paper(Efficient Intrusion Detection with Reduced Dimension Using Data Mining Classification Methods and Their Performance Comparison) and I select 14 potential attribute and then based on your response were normalized instanse of any feature.After normalization, how do I know which any instance of this features is related to package(normal or attack)??I'm confused,I do not know what should I do after normalization??How do I identify this Package???

Answer (score 1):

Once you have normalized data, train the svm using cross-validation to select good parameters. Then any new packet should have the same normalization applied to as was applied to the training data. You can then use the model from training to predict the label for the new packet.
The exact details of this depend on which SVM implementation you are using. In any case, http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf is recommended reading.

Comment: No need to write a "thanks" comment. If an answer is useful upvote it. If it solves your problem then accept it. And if the answer is rubbish, downvote it.